# Does Debian GNU/Hurd support ext4 filesystem?

Tags: debian, ext4, hurd

I have downloaded Debian GNU/Hurd disk image. However, while the virtual machine was running, my PC crash along with the virtual machine. I tried to start the virtual machine, but many things were not working because the filesystem was damaged. As far as I know, EXT4 is a journaling filesystem, so any damage to the filesystem should be recoverable if the filesystem is EXT4. Now I want to convert the root filesystem (from a backup copy of the disk image) from EXT2 to EXT4. I know that's possible, but I'm not sure whether Debian GNU/Hurd supports EXT4 formatted filesystems.

Comment: While I cannot answer this: how about you try installing it on a USB flash drive and just test it out?

Comment: @FelixJN My computer runs GNU/Linux with many problems and requires nonfree drivers. So running GNU/Hurd is impossible on my PC.

Comment: Well, another VM with ext4-based Hurd then? It's just about running a test.

Comment: @FelixJN VM test boot failed!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I’m aware, there’s no translator for Ext4, whether in Debian specifically or in the Hurd in general. [The existing `ext2fs` translator](https://www.gnu.org/software/hurd/hurd/translator/ext2fs.html) doesn’t support Ext4, and the version packaged in Debian doesn’t either.